# Multiple Registration Form with redux and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been trying to develop a dashboard form similiar to airbnb listing form for understanding more deeply about react redux but i am stuck in the middle of my project. I have a multiple form where when user clicks on continue button the user will get another form to fill and so on and if user clicks on back button the user will get form of one step back with previously filled values. I could not decide what should i do for this. Do i have to create a object in action as listingName . summary, name, email etc as empty value and update it with reducer using Object.assign() or what. Till now i could only develop like when user clicks on personal tab a form related to personal information is shown and when user clicks on basic tab, a form related to basic information is shown. I want all form data to be send to server at last submit. What should i do now ? Do i use increment and decrement action for the continue and back button and use submit action on the last form button ? Could you please provide me an idea ?

[image: dashboard form]

Here's my code

**actions/index.js**

```
export function selectForm(form){
  return{
    type: 'FORM_SELECTED',
    payload: form
  };

}
```

**reducers/reducer_active_form.js**

```
export default function(state=null, action){
  let newState = Object.assign({},state);
  switch(action.type){
    case 'FORM_SELECTED':
      return action.payload;
  }
  return state;
}
```

**reducers/reducer_form_option.js**

```
export default function(){
  return[
    { option: 'Personal Information', id:1},
    { option: 'Basic Information', id:2 },
    { option: 'Description', id:3},
    { option: 'Location', id:4},
    { option: 'Amenities', id:5},
    { option: 'Gallery', id:6}
  ]
}
```

**containers/form-details**

```
class FormDetail extends Component{
  renderPersonalInfo(){
    return(
      <div className="personalInfo">
        <div className="col-md-4">
          <label htmlFor='name'>Owner Name</label>
          <input ref="name" type="textbox" className="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Owner name" />
        </div>

        <div className="col-md-4">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input ref="email" type="email" className="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email" />
        </div>

        <div className="col-md-4">
          <label htmlFor="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
          <input ref="phone" type="textbox" className="form-control" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="phone number" />
        </div>

        <div className="buttons">
          <button className="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
        </div>

      </div>
      );
  }

  renderBasicInfo(){
    return(
       <div>
              <h3>Help Rent seekers find the right fit</h3>
              <p className="subtitle">People searching on Rental Space can filter by listing basics to find a space that matches their needs.</p>
              <hr/>
              <div className="col-md-4 basicForm">
                  <label htmlFor="price">Property Type</label>
                  <select className="form-control" name="Property Type" ref="property">
                      <option value="appartment">Appartment</option>
                      <option value="house">House</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4 basicForm">
                  <label htmlFor="price">Price</label>
                  <input type="textbox" ref="price" className="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Enter Price" required />
              </div>
              <div className="buttons">
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Back</button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
              </div>
            </div>
      );
  }

  renderDescription(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h3>Tell Rent Seekers about your space</h3>
            <hr/>
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <label htmlFor="listingName">Listing Name</label>
                <input ref="name" type="textbox" className="form-control" id="listingName" placeholder="Be clear" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
                <label htmlFor="summary">Summary</label>
                <textarea ref="summary" className="form-control" id="summary" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
             <div className="buttons">
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Back</button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
             </div>
        </div>
      );
  }

  renderLocation(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h3>Help guests find your place</h3>
            <p className="subtitle">will use this information to find a place that’s in the right spot.</p>
            <hr/>
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
                <input ref="city" type="textbox" className="form-control" id="city" placeholder="Biratnagar" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <label htmlFor="placeName">Name of Place</label>
                <input ref="place" type="textbox" className="form-control" id="placeName" placeholder="Ganesh Chowk" />
            </div>
             <div className="buttons">
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Back</button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
             </div>
        </div>
      );
  }

  render(){
    if ( !this.props.form){
      return this.renderPersonalInfo();
    }

    const type = this.props.form.option;
    console.log('type is', type);

    if ( type === 'Personal Information'){
      return this.renderPersonalInfo();
    }

    if ( type === 'Basic Information'){
      return this.renderBasicInfo();
    }

    if ( type === 'Description'){
      return this.renderDescription();
    }

    if ( type === 'Location'){
      return this.renderLocation();
    }
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state){

  return{
    form: state.activeForm
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FormDetail);
```

Answer (score 6):

The first thing you're missing is controlled components. By giving the inputs a `value` property, and an `onChange` function, you will link the input with an external state.

Your components should have access, via react-redux, to the state and actions needed. The `value` of the form should be your state for that object. So you might have a state like:

```
location: {
  listingName: '123 Main St',
  summary: 'The most beautiful place!'
}
```

Then, you'd just pass each property to inputs. I'm assuming, in this example, that you've passed the `location` prop in `mapStateToProps`, and an `actions` object with all the related actions in `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
changeHandler(ev, fieldName) {
  const val = ev.target.value;
  this.props.actions.updateField(fieldName, val);
},

render() {
  return (
    <input 
      value={this.props.location.listingName} 
      onChange={(ev) => { this.changeHandler(ev, 'listingName'}} 
    />
  );
}
```

You provide it an action that can be used to update the state:

```
function updatefield(field, val) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_FIELD,
    field,
    val
  };
}
```

Then, you just merge it in, in your reducer

```
switch (action.type) {
  case UPDATE_FIELD:
    state = { ...state, [action.field]: val };
```

(using dynamic keys and spread operator for neatness, but it's similar to Object.assign)

All of your form state lives in the Redux store this way. When you are ready to submit that data to the server, you can either use async actions with [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), or set up some [middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) to run the calls. Either way, the strategy is the same; your state lasts locally and populates all your forms, and then is sent to the server when the user submits.

I went through this pretty quick, let me know if you need me to elaborate on anything :)

Comment: Thanks i will try this and let you know. So in my reducer it should be like this location: {
  listingName: '123 Main St',
  summary: 'The most beautiful place!'
}

personal:{
 ownerName: 'name of owner',
 email: 'email address',
 phoneNumber: 'phone number'
} and provide onChange event handler on all the input field , right ?

Comment: For transition of form while clicking next and back i need to provide different action ( INCREMENT_FIELD and DECREMENT_FIELD) ?

Comment: To your first comment: Yep! There are different ways you can do it but I've found it easiest to do it as I've shown. Each input gets the same onChange handler, but with different arguments. Because you have a `location` and a `personal` tree, you can either create two functions, or you can add a third argument. `updateField('location', 'listingName', val)`

Comment: To your second: it depends, in my opinion, on if there is complex logic to say whether or not you can transition between forms. I would probably have a `SWITCH_FORM_VIEW` action, which takes a `formName` argument. Then, in your component, you can set up conditional renders based on that field. In your reducer state, you'll want another top-level property of `currentFormView` that holds the value submitted by that action.

Comment: It also sounds like you're starting to get to the point where it might make sense to have multiple reducers: you could have one for `location`, one for `personal`, and a general `ui` one that controls things like which form is visible. Don't worry about it for now (focus on just getting everything working), but if you're looking to refactor afterwards, google `combineReducers`

Comment: I have created a github repo . I will be trying putting all the knowledge you shared with me .

Comment: you can improve your event handling by giving a name to your input and using that name as the state variable. that way you dont need the inline function to pass through what the name of it is. it'll make your answer look better :) aka `name="listingName"` and the event handler `onChange={this.changeHandler}` and then inside that function `this.props.actions.updateField(ev.target.name, ev.target.value);`

Comment: also @pri I would recommend you have one parent component that controls the active view of all of the forms. use an active index to show each page, and increment it or decrement it when the user hits next or previous (you can also prevent the next view based off of form validation, just wouldn't increment the active index until it is a valid form)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using react-redux you can use the redux-form. It will greatly help you with the coding as it will simplify your work load and it is also bug-free (as far as I know). In my opinion you would want to use all the libraries/frameworks provided to you as you want to be as **agile** as possible.

Also the redux-form has a wizard form implementation. I think that is exactly what you are looking for.

http://erikras.github.io/redux-form/#/examples/wizard?_k=yspolv

Just follow the link and you will see a very good tutorial on how to implement it. Should be a piece of cake.

Comment: I wanted to do by myself so I can understand the flow of redux well and understand what should be done in such situations, how action, reducers have to be designed. Anyhow thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: you can do the simple tutorial to get the basics. Then you just want to develop as fast as you can. Things are not staying as they are for long. Specially the front-end development is crazily fast-paced.

Comment: When learning a new technology, there is immense value in doing things from scratch. You're asking for trouble if you use a bunch of tools you don't understand, because the second your use-case gets more complicated (or the tool doesn't work as you expect), you have no idea what to do.

Comment: True that stuff is changing very fast but redux in particular is a great thing to learn. Teaches you tons about functional programming in general :)

Comment: Fair enough! You can just refer to that link and try and study the code.

Comment: Sure i will do that . Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Theo, the link you provided is broken though.